# Jagged array in VBA 7.0 - syntax error

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I'm using Excel 2010, and I wonder why the below code doesn't work for me? I've got `compile error: syntax error`.

```
Sub test()
Dim myStudents(,) As String = _       
   {{"Dick", "Jane", "Tom", "Sam"}, _
   {"Sue", "Bill", "Mary", ""}}    
End Sub
```

[Example link](http://visualbasic.about.com/b/2007/05/11/initializing-a-jagged-array.htm) and code :

```
Sub xyz()
    Dim xyz()()() As Byte
End Sub
```

This also produced `compile error: syntax error` when ran.

Comment: Define "doesn't work".  Are you getting an error?

Comment: I get 'compile error:syntax error' because of 'myStydents(,)' structure

Comment: I don't think jagged arrays are available in VBA (VBA <> VB). You will need to use an array of arrays.

Comment: lol I've missed 'A' in 'VBA' thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is VB.net syntax. VB.net is not the same as VBA, which is what is used in Excel, etc. To do this in VBA you can do something like:

```
Public Sub test()
  Dim myStudents() As Variant

  myStudents = Array( _
                 Array("Dick", "Jane", "Tom", "Sam"), _
                 Array("Sue", "Bill", "Mary") _
               )

  Debug.Print myStudents(0)(1) ' Jane
  Debug.Print myStudents(1)(2) ' Mary
End Sub
```

i.e., We create an array of arrays.